# How to disable Magento_Banner module?

Tags: magento2, module, uninstall-module

I know its a simple question, but I am getting an issue while disabling my `Magento_Banner`.

I followed this doc

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html

But i am getting this error `Table magento_banner do not have a column with name banner_id` on running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.

[image]

on running `bin/magento module:disable Magento_Banner`

[image]

Comment: just add that column and try again hope it works!

Comment: Try using SSH command: php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Banner

Comment: have you added and schema file for table creation?

Comment: and follow this https://magenticians.com/enable-disable-magento-2-extensions/

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel banner_id column is already in the banner table, only getting this error on disabling the module

Comment: @SanjayGohil getting error, see updated question

Comment: @summu please refer URL which I shared.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel so i need to disable all 6 dependent modules of banner first,

Comment: @summu no please first try only which you want to disable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102571/discussion-between-summu-and-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel).

Answer (score 1):

You may add following code in the bottom of the *app/etc/config.php* file.
Add the code starting from  *'system' => [*

```
   'Yotpo_Yotpo' => 1
    ],
    'system' => [
        'websites' => [
            'base' => [
                'advanced' => [
                    'modules_disable_output' => [
                        'Magento_Banner' => '1'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

After that run *setup:upgrade* command.

Comment: Just make sure to replace your website code instead of 'base' 
It's required in multi-site.

Answer (score 0):

**Things to Remember While Enabling or Disabling Magento 2 Extensions**

Some modules(e.g `Magento_Banner`) have dependencies on other modules due to which, modules can be disabled or enabled. Here are some examples of it:

- If Module A depends on module B, then you have to disable Module A first because you cannot disable Module B directly.
- If Module A depends on module B, then you have to enable Module B
  first because you cannot enable Module A directly.
- If Module A conflicts with Module B then you cannot enable Module A
  and Module B at the same time. However, you can disable Module A and
  Module B, or you can disable either module.

**[Updated]**

**Disable module output in a simple deployment**

The procedure for disabling module output on a single instance of Magento is easier because the changes don’t have to be distributed.

1. Archive the original
   `<Magento_install_dir>/vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/config.xml`
   file.
2. Add lines similar to the following to the `<Magento_install_dir>/vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/config.xml` file, directly under the `<default>` element:

   ```
   <default>
       <advanced>
           <modules_disable_output>
               <Magento_Banner>1</Magento_Banner>
           </modules_disable_output>
       </advanced>
       ............
   </default>
   ```

Run the following command to export the configuration changes:

`$ bin/magento app:config:dump`

The results are written to the /app/etc/config.php file.

Next, clear the cache to enable the new setting:

`$ bin/magento cache:clean config`

Go to admin->content->content. 
You can see **Dynamic Block** is disabled.

> See the below link to get more in detail

[Disable module output](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html)

Comment: i already tried this, no success,

Comment: Updated my answer. Check wheather you are doing the same. Becouse Its verified in M233.